# Will React submit my form through PHP once it's on a hosting site with an actual server (Heroku) or do i need to use different code?

Tags: php, reactjs, forms

Will React submit my form through PHP once it's on a hosting site with an actual server (Heroku) or do i need to use different code?

I'm using a react app for my website and in a contact page i have a form that i use action="form.php" but of course when i submit i get an error "cannot POST form.php. Probably because there is no server. My question is once i upload it to my hosting or heroku, will  it automatically work or do i need to use different method than action... ?

I've tried other solutions but nothing worked

```
class ProjectReqs extends Component {
    render() {


        return (
        <div>


    <form action="./components/webform.php" class="webform" method="post">
        <h4>Let's Design a beautiful Website</h4>
        <h5>Please fill out your requirements for your website project below.</h5>

        <div class="webformgenerate"></div>
        <div class="webcustomreqsspace"></div> 

        <button class="submit-btn" name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button class="preview-btn wpb">Preview</button>
        <span class="tooltip">You must preview and save before submitting</span>

    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: It will work if you have PHP support and a file called `form.php` with the code you need. If the question is about your code, please share it and explain what your struggling with. If the question is about how the Heroku service works, you should contact their support/forum/etc.

Comment: i updated my question with the code. thanks

Comment: Does the file `components/webform.php` actually exist? Does it work? Do you have a local web server with PHP support? If not, you should fix all those things first. Get it working locally before you put it online.

Comment: of course my file webform.php exists.

Comment: so you think if i install a local server with php this error should go away and send the email?

Comment: I can't really answer that since I have no idea what that code does, but yes, you would most likely need to install some type of server with PHP support. You could start by checking out something like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).

Comment: yes i have XAMPP. thanks Magnus